# Can Matlab optimize an external process?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I'm considering buying Matlab Home + Optimization module for home use, however I'm not sure it can do what I want it to.

I have an external process (not Matlab) that takes input, runs a process, and produces output.  I want to tie in the input and output to Matlab so that Matlab can "optimize" these inputs, completely blind to the discrete process itself.  Does Matlab have discrete optimization capabilities, or do all of its optimization functions rely on having internal access to the process itself?

Thanks!

-Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your external process is capable to assimilate parameters and give response to a external program using any methods eg, command line, or files,  yes it is possible just configure your objective function to send and read the parameters and response data to the external process.

For the discrete optimization, the optimization toolbox do not work with discrete optimizations problems, but the documentation give a hint about rounding the parameter inside the objective function and then running again in the responses variable.

for example, this can be a function to optimize a volume of a prism
which is coded in a external program written in python (just for demonstration purpose with single objetive genetic algorithm (*ga*)):

```
function f = optim(x)
    %Optimization criteria
    l = round(x(1));
    h = round(x(2));
    w = round(x(3));

    %String to produce the external proccess call as a system command        
    commandStr = ['python -c "print ' num2str(l) ' * ' num2str(h) ' * ' num2str(w) ' "'];

    %Execute the system command, status = 0 for good execution
    [status, commandOut] = system(commandStr);

    %Convert the output of the external program from strin to doble and assign as the response of the optimization funcition
    f = str2double(commandOut)
```

Then you can use the `optimtool` using this funcion as objetive as:

[image]

Then export the result to workspace and `round()` it.

Or make it programmable with a code like this:

```
function [x,fval] = runOptimization(lb,ub)
    options = gaoptimset;
    options = gaoptimset(options,'Display', 'off');
    [x,fval] =ga(@optim,3,[],[],[],[],lb,ub,[],[],options);
    x = round(x)
    fval = optim(x)
```

And run as

```
[x,fval] = runOptimization([1 1 1],[3 4 5])
```

**NOTE**. the `round()` functions its only to demonstrate how to do discrete optimization as suggested in the documentation